# How to get the currently activte activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

My app has several activities. I need to determine which one of them is currently active (or whatever the term is, active, foreground, showing, ...). Is there a way to do this?

(I thought this is an easy and commonly-used thing, but after searching for half and hour, I got nothing. :-(

(RunningTaskInfo.topActivity() only returns the ComponentName, but I need its reference, so this doesn't help.)

(A brute-force solution is to keep track of the activity's reference in a global variable. But this has to be done in each and every onResume(). It's ugly IMO.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. 'What', exactly, needs to determine the currently active Activity? Activities themselves obviously know 'who they are' (if you see what I mean) so I can only guess you need something 'external' to know which Activity is active...or have I mis-interpreted? A further explanation of what you're trying to achieve might help.

Comment: @PeterSmith, thank you. Well, the case is actually very simple: When the program flow goes deep, like 8 or 10 levels down to the database engine or some common routine, the activity reference got lost somewhere in the calling chain. So, yes, a deligent programmer should faithfully pass that reference no matter where the program flows, but .... I got lazy. So I'm thinking maybe there is an Android class can provide this handy information. After all, it must be very common in progamming that a routine deep in the bottom got called by everyone needs to know the activity calling it. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever came across this problem, i.e., you need a reference to the current active activity, there is no a real solution here. The only way is you keep track of it by yourself, using a global. Yes, using a global is really not the best way for Android programming, but I think it's less costly.

Here is what I did:

Extend all my acitivities from the same base activity: MotherOfAllActivities.

```
public class MotherOfAllActivities extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(...) {
        globalCurrentActivity = this;
        ........
    }

    public void onResume() {
        globalCurrentActivity = this;
        ........
    }

    public void onPause() {
        if (globalCurrentActivity == this)
            globalCurrentActivity = null;
    }

    // And, don't forget about onActivityResult(). It can come before onResume()
    // of the calling activity and after onPause() of the called activity. That is,
    // there is a window when globalCurrentActivity is null.
    public void onActivityResult() {
        globalCurrentActivity = this;
    }
}
```

Don't shoot me if you don't like this answer. I'm just trying to share with people of what works for me, at least so far.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this creates a big memory leak. edit: It definitely does. If you're new to (java) programming, you'd be doing yourself a huge favor by figuring out WHY this is the case, and HOW to get around this.

Comment: please explain why it causes a memory leak

Comment: The memory leak occurs because the activity and all of it's siblings do not get garbage collected. To avoid a memory leak you can use a WeakReference<Activity> for the globalCurrentActivity;

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this?

Not really.

> (A brute-force solution is to keep track of the activity's reference in a global variable. But this has to be done in each and every onResume(). It's ugly IMO.)

It's also a recipe for memory leaks.

Personally, I'd find a better way to solve whatever problem you think your are solving by getting the "currently activte [sic] activity".

Comment: Well, the problem to solve in the first place is actually very simple: When the program goes deep, the activity reference is lost somewhere in the calling chain. So, yes, another option is to add a parameter to all the methods along the way from top to bottom. But that's not pretty either, IMO.

Comment: No, there won't be memory leak, it should be a *global* global variable, like in Application or alike. Besides, this variable can't be kept inside Activity, which is the recipe for memory leak, because I don't have the reference to the activity in the first place! :-)

Comment: @wwyt: A "*global* global variable", to use your tortured phrase, is the #1 cause of memory leaks. In fact, one could argue that any memory leak in a GC environment stems, in one form or fashion from a "*global* global variable", whether one declared by the developer or by the runtime engine (e.g., roster of running threads). Putting an `Activity` in a static data member, or in an `Application`, will be a memory leak unless you *always* clear out that data member, and if you think you have trouble passing objects through methods, you'll never catch all the cases to clear it out.

Comment: hmmmm...., looks like I've been wrong all along. I'm new to Java, did some study on memory leaks. But so far the only article I found useful is the one by Romaine Guy (?) in his blog. But the impression I got are: 1. MLs are rare (because the article titled ML, and he mentioned only one case, so I thought maybe there aren't many possibilities could cause ML so he didn't mention more.....; 2. As long as the static member is not in an activity, which will be passed around and into the system and back as he pointed out, then I'm safe. Could you please share some links on this? Thks.

Comment: Actually, you know what? If it leaks, then I'll just let it leak! It's just a few activities (no images or videos), how big can they be? My app is not the kind that stays alive for a whole day, the process will be killed after a short while, and given giga bytes of device memory nowadays, users won't even feel it. But comparing to adding a parameter to almost all methods, this is defenitely worth it! (Heh heh heh, I'm evil.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not nearly an expert but i needed to do something like you mention keep a current highlighted button highlighted (bottom bar). I think i used onResume() in each activity as you mention to store it in a application class variable. I'm sure there is a better way though

Edit: actually i just re-read what you proposed... yeah i agree with commonsware storing an actual reference to the activity is bad. Why can't you just store a string variable of the name of the current activity? thats what i did to keep track and highlight an appropriate button

Comment: The name? But I need its reference so that I can use it in, e.g., currentActivity.findViewById(). If all you need is the name, then maybe you should checkout ActivityManager.getRunningTasks() and RunningTaskInfo.topActivity()?

Comment: Actually it wasn't the current topActivity() name i was after it was a current tab within the tab host of that topActivity. I'm sure there were better ways to do things though i'll revisit it one day Cheers